# C++ double returning a 0 instead of 0.1

Tags: c++

So I'm trying my hand at C++ again and I'm writing a function that keeps giving the wrong value.

I've boiled it down to a line basically this: double testD = (10/100); that gives me 0 instead of 0.1.

I might have missed something major but I thought double held decimal values? For the life of me I can't get this to be correct.

Please help me (even if I'm terribly stupid).

Comment: That might work, but as I said 'boiled down.' The 10 in that equation is actually target.getMagicDef() from a class that returns an integer value of 10.

Comment: Then `static_cast<double>(10)/100`.

Comment: or assign it to a `double` variable first i.e. `double d = target.getMagicDef();`

Answer (score 0):

`10` and `100` are integers. This will result in integer division, which will evaluate to `0`. That `0` will then be stored in `testD`.

To force floating-point division cast one of the numbers to float or double.

```
((double)whatever)/something
```

Comment: Is there an elegant way to add .0 to a returned integer value?

Comment: I edited my answer. Just cast it to double.